# Find nearest item given an angle in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, angle

Given a numpy 2D array, what would be the best way to get the nearest item (for this example '1') from a specified coordinate (where 'X' is located) given an angle.

For example, lets say we have 'X' located at (1,25) in a 2D array shown below.  Say with an angle 225 degrees, assuming 0 degrees goes straight to the right and 90 degrees goes straight up.  How can I get the nearest coordinate of a '1' located towards that vector direction?

```
[
0000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000X00
0000000000000000000000000000
1110000000000000000000000000
1111100000000000000000000000
1111110000000000000000000000
1111111000000000000000000000
1111111110000000000000000000
1111111111100000000000000000
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by towards that direction you mean something like on that ray. In that case 255° has no solution so I took the liberty of changing that to 195°.

You could then brute-force it:

```
import numpy as np

a = """
0000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000X00
0000000000000000000000000000
1110000000000000000000000000
1111100000000000000000000000
1111110000000000000000000000
1111111000000000000000000000
1111111110000000000000000000
1111111111100000000000000000
"""

a = np.array([[int(i) for i in row] for row in a.strip().replace('X', '2').split()], dtype=np.uint8)

x = np.argwhere(a==2)[0]
y = np.argwhere(a==1)
d = y-x

phi = 195 # 255 has no solutions

on_ray = np.abs(d@(np.sin(np.radians(-phi-90)), np.cos(np.radians(-phi-90))))<np.sqrt(0.5)

show_ray = np.zeros_like(a)
show_ray[tuple(y[on_ray].T)] = 1
print(show_ray)

ymin=y[on_ray][np.argmin(np.einsum('ij,ij->i', d[on_ray], d[on_ray]))]
print(ymin)
```

Output:

```
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
# [6 6]
```

Comment: Yea I just picked an arbitrary angle, thought that would hit the ones.  Trying to understand your solution.  I know what 'd' is, but I'm trying to understand how that played a role in determining the on_ray.  I guess that was used to determine the angles toward each of the 1s?  Also, what does 'd@' do exaclty? Thanks

Comment: `@` is matrix multiplication. Here it is used to mass evaluate scalar products. As you can see we are not multiplying with the ray direction but with the ray directioni turned by 90°. That is a so called normal vector. The beauty of the normal vector is that the scalar prdouct gives you the distance (with sign for above or below) from the ray. So we pick all the `1`s that are within sqrt(1/2) of the ray. The sqrt(1/2) is a bit sloppy, I have to admit.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info.  From your answer I was able to use unit vector of unit_vector = np.cos(np.radians(-phi-90)), -np.sin(np.radians(-phi-90)), then from the coordinate of x (starting point), keep incrementing the starting coord (and rounding/int) with the unit vector and check if the matrix value in that coord is '1'.  Do it until you find '1' or its out of bounds.  Basically keep moving down the line of the unit vector until you hit a '1' or its out of bounds.  You think that would be faster? Since your solution evaluates all 1s and if the array is quite large, it could be slower

Comment: Maybe. Depends on how large your grid is I think. The thing is that a Python loop is much slower than vectorized operations, so you need to save a lot of work to be faster with a loop. You'll have to try and use `timeit.timeit` to compare. Probably the most promising strategy would be to compute the coordinates of the gridpoints on or near the ray in a vectorized way maybe using `np.linspace` with `dtype=int` and then check for ones at these coordinates.

Comment: True, python loops are much slower.  Thanks again for the info.